# Capture a Value in SQL

Tags: sql

I want to capture the last value recorded right before a certain time was recorded. In Healthcare terms I need the max flowsheet value 0-10 that was recorded right before a pain medication was given.

I can add the max(flowsheet recorded time) but I am not sure how to add in the time of the medication so I get the max value that was recorded.

Comment: You know the time? Then you can write the `WHERE` clause to only look at entries before that time. Of these rows select the desired maximum value with `MAX`.

Comment: not sure how to write in sql to get the value i need. can you possibly send me an example ?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with, the where clause or the select clause with the max function? And what DBMS are you using? You should always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS in order to get answers that work for your database system.

Comment: I think I have the correct max function in my select statement to get me the max value for the flowsheet value but I am not sure where to add the medication time so it pulls the flowsheet value that was done right before the medication was given ?? Does that make sense ? So, give me the last value that  was recorded right before the medication was given (med time)

Comment: How do you know the med time? Do you find it in the same table or another table or do you just know it? Please show the query that you have. And again: What is your DBMS?

Comment: Yes the med time is in another table. Our DBMS is a Relational DB. It is EPIC (Electronic Patient Medical Record).

Comment: How do I post the whole query, believe it is too big.

Comment: Then simplify the query and reduce it to the part you are talking about. Use the `{}` button when you edit your request to mark the query as code.

Comment: Please don't edit my answer, if you want to add information. Edit your request instead.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to capture the last value recorded right before a certain time was recorded. In Healthcare terms I need the max flowsheet value 0-10 that was recorded right before a pain medication was given.

We know little about your database, so here is the general approach. You want to look at rows before the medication (`where mydate < medication_date`). Of these rows, you say you to want the maximum flowsheet value (`max(flowsheet)`).

Furthermore, in your request comments you say the medication_date is in another table.

Putting these things together we get something like:

```
select max(flowsheet)
from mytable
where mydate < (select medication_date from medication);
```

Well, the medication table won't really have just one row with the global medication date. So let's assume both tables refer to patients, and you want the information for a particular patient. This would be something like this:

```
select max(flowsheet)
from mytable t
where patient_id = 12345
and mydate < 
(
  select medication_date
  from medication m
  where m.patient_id = t.patient_id
);
```